# Strange top line on the frame when rendering with Cycles (OPTIX)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, render-passes

I get a strange obscur line on the top border of my frame.
I am rendering with Optix on a RTX 2070 super with 1000samples with denoiser (CYCLES).
I dont have this problem when rendering with Cuda.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks a lot,
i wish you a great day !

Simon

[image: Render problem]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did this bar still come after saving it as an image and opening the image up?

Comment: Unfortunatly yes